# Asking a question in topic $X$,now it seems like it's related to topic $Y$ which OP don't know about it.what action(s) should be taken?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

So here is the weird story...

> I was solving questions from a chapter of a book that was about  **equation solving and system of equations** and the book subjects are **precalculus algebra**.and there was question there which I was not able to solve it.So I asked it on [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924596/solve-x3y-4y3-y3z-4z3-z3x-4x3-in-reals) and I tagged question with with [systems-of-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systems-of-equations) , [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) and [polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials). After the time passed and comments and answers started to showing up, it became obvious that the question is related to [algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-geometry) and [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) which I don't know about this topics and my knowledge is very minimum there.

So my questions and problems are

1- As the two answers on my question are not related to the tags subjects that I have chosen for my question, why those answers are posted when they won't have a benefit for OP. Albeit thanks to people who put time and effort to answer my questions, but isn't tags are a sign of which topics OP is familiar with them? They could have asked me in comments about that I'm familiar with those topics or not, So  then posting their answers.

2-As it turned out that the question is not solvable with precalculus techniques,and there solutions that are related to other topics like calculus, should I change the tags of my questions? As I think people who are familiar with those topics could benefit from this question and its answers.

3-As it is my fault that asking this question which is not in the topics that I familiar with them and there are two answer that seems to be right and useful, what should I do about accepting answer?

Comment: This seems, to some extent, related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11419/is-it-ok-to-answer-a-question-with-a-higher-level-of-mathematics-than-i-expect-t

Comment: I have removed [meta-tag:specific-user] tag, since [this tag is for](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-user) *questions which focus on a particular user, rather than those discussing general user issues.* If I misunderstood your question and you do not want to discuss this in general but only one particular instance, feel free to change the tags. But if it is the case, [meta-tag:specific-question] would be a more appropriate tag and it would be useful to link to the question.